# Kmeans - Find the closest distance between two points of two cluster

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means, nearest-neighbor

I'm using a csv file to divide into 2 clusters. The blue one is the benign URL and the red one is the malicious URL. The problem is my instructor want to know the closest point of two clusters and the distance between them. I tried to use the distance between two centroids but it didn't work!
Thank you for your help!
Here the code and and the clusters:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("major_combined.csv")
X_mal = data.iloc[:,[1, 5, 6, 11, 13, 15, 19, 20, 23]]

kmeans_mal = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='random', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state = 0)
y_kmeans_mal = kmeans_mal.fit_predict(X_mal)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(X_mal.iloc[y_kmeans_mal == 0,4], X_mal.iloc[y_kmeans_mal == 0,8], s= 100, color = 'blue', label ='0')
plt.scatter(X_mal.iloc[y_kmeans_mal == 1,4], X_mal.iloc[y_kmeans_mal == 1,8], s= 100, color = 'red', label ='1')
plt.scatter(kmeans_mal.cluster_centers_[:,4], kmeans_mal.cluster_centers_[:,8], s= 300, color = 'yellow', label ='Centroid')
plt.title('k-means clustering')
plt.xlabel('document')
plt.ylabel('window')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: The k-means clustering]

Comment: Perhaps your instructor wants to know which two points, in different clusters, are the nearest?  You could exhaustively measure the distance between all pairs and report the nearest.

Comment: May I ask how to measure the distance between of all pairs in Python?

Comment: Psuedo-code to find a single pair (code will need to be adjusted if mindist isn't unique and all pairs are desired): `mindist=huge_num;p0_gold=None;p1_gold=None;for p0 in cluster0: for p1 in cluster1: p_dist=distance(p0,p1):if (p_dist< mindist): (mindist=p_dist;p0_gold=p0;p1_gold=p1)`